# How to color plotly bubble chart by any category variable

Tags: r, plot

I have data set as below and stored in data frame `dt`

```
dt = data.frame(category=c("A","B","C"),X=c(1,2,3),Y=c(3,4,5))
```

and am trying to plot bubble chart using `plotly` as below and color it by category

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(dt, x =X, y = Y, size = X, mode = "markers",color = category)
```

But it is not showing the bubble chart properly.

Comment: I guess you cannot map colors to characters, which is the content of `category`. This one `plot_ly(dt, x =X, y = Y, size = X, mode = "markers",color = as.numeric(category))` works.

Comment: But in Plotly we page samples, there are graphs shown with character type of data. Refer: http://help.plot.ly/make-a-bubble-chart/

Comment: Refer: http://help.plot.ly/make-a-bubble-chart/

Comment: But this via the website, right? Not through the R package?

Comment: Am just thinking, If it is possible in UI, then it should be possible in UI also right.

Answer (score 0):

I think its a bug and I believe the folks at Plotly are working on it. See [here](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues).

I think it has to do with the number of unique points being shown on the x-axis and the number of unique size values. See below for an illustration.

- First example has 10 points but 10 unique sizes as well
- Second example has 10 points but only 5 unique sizes

---

```
set.seed(123)

# This doesn't work 
N<- 10
dt <- data.frame(category = sample(LETTERS, size = N, replace = T),
               X = 1:N, 
               Y = 1:N)

plot_ly(dt, x = X, y = Y, color = category, mode = "markers", size = X)

# But this works
N<- 10
dt <- data.frame(category = sample(LETTERS, size = N/2, replace = T),
               X = 1:N, 
               Y = 1:N)

plot_ly(dt, x = X, y = Y, color = category, mode = "markers", size = X)
```

---

For your example, you could try using `ggplotly()` instead:

```
dt = data.frame(category=c("A","B","C"),X=c(1,2,3),Y=c(3,4,5))
ggplot(dt, aes(X, Y, size = X, color = category)) + geom_point()
ggplotly()
```

Hope this helps.